# Proof of a proposition about differentiablity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:R^{n}→R$ be differentiable at point $x∈R^{n}$, and suppose that $v$ is a unit vector. Prove that:$∂f/∂v(x)=∇f(x)·v$.

I have no idea for a prove so far. The only hint I've got is that it is to rely on the properties of $d_{x}f$, including the fact that $d_{x}f$ is a linear map. But I cannot follow the hint. So could someone please give a full proof, using the hint or otherwise, of the proposition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is $\partial f/\partial v(x)$ defined in your text? Is it defined as $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}(f(x + tv) - f(x))$?

Comment: @kobe Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb R^n$, we define $\gamma(t)=x+tv,\ t\in\mathbb R$.
By the chain rule: 
$$
D_v f(x)=\frac d{dt}f(x+tv)|_{t=0}=\frac d{dt} (f\circ \gamma) |_{t=0}=\\
=D(f\circ \gamma) |_{t=0}=Df(\gamma(0))D\gamma(0)=\\
=\left(\partial_{x_1} f(\gamma(0)),\dots, \partial_{x_n} f(\gamma(0))  \right)\cdot \left(\frac d{dt}\gamma_1(0), \dots, \frac d{dt}\gamma_n(0)\right)^T=\\
=\nabla f(x)\cdot v.
$$

Comment: May I ask for a proof using limit definition?

Comment: Start from $\lim_{t\to 0} (f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(0)))$

Comment: @Y.X. the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}f(x + tv)\big|_{t = 0}$ is by definition $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}(f(x + tv) - f(x))$.

Comment: May I ask for a more explicit explain from your second line to the third line?

Comment: @Y.X. Just unrolling the definition $D\gamma(0)=\frac d{d t} (x+tv)=v$

Answer (score 0):

Define $\gamma(t)=x+tv$, and define $F(t)=f\circ \gamma (t)$. Then as $f$ is differentiable, by chain rule

$$
F'(t)=f_{x_1} \gamma '(t)+\cdots +f_{x_n}\gamma'(t) = \nabla f \cdot \gamma'(t) = \nabla f \cdot v
$$

But in fact

$$
\nabla f \cdot v= F'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+vt)-f(x)}{t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)
$$